# MVC framework - use of '$this'

Tags: php, design-patterns, model-view-controller, view

Is it correct to call controller methods and access its attributes through `$this` variable when inside a view?

Lets say Im running 'index' view from 'Calcs' controller:

Calcs controller:

```
class Calcs extends Controller{

    public function index(){

        $this->set('number', 1);
        $this->set('number2', 4);
        $this->set('number3', 5);
        $this->set('number4', 2);

    }

    public function doComplexStuff($n1, $n2){
        return $n1 + $n2;
    }

}
```

View "index.phtml":

```
// Html ...
echo $this->doComplexStuff($number, $number2); //5
echo $this->doComplexStuff($number3, $number4); //7
```

Then i have another controller that also uses 'doComplexStuff' from 'Calcs'

```
class Another extends Controller{

    public function randomView(){

        $calcsController = ControllerFactory::getController('Calcs');
        $myRandomNumber = $calcsController->doComplexStuff(rand(), rand());
        $this->set('myRandomNumber', $myRandomNumber);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach in the current MVC frameworks is to pass any results from the controller to the view. One of the ways to do that is to assign them to the view instance as local or global variables.

Avoid calling any controller or model methods inside your views. Use views to display data, controllers to control the flow of your application and models to do do the business logic. This is just a general recommendation/principle implemented in the MVC pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller.

For a example of the approach taken in Laravel framework,go here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views

```
$view = View::make('greeting')->with('name', 'Steve');
```

This way your views will contain only the logic to display the data that they have received from the controller that called them.

Answer (score 0):

Controller is layer which handles requests and delegates data to view. The view layer should just display this data. That's why it is called view. So all calculations should be done in controller. Controller then sends data to view and view doesn't do any calculations and handles displaying of data.

Comment: Actually, calculations should usually be in the model.

Comment: Well, I agree. I didn't want to complicate things with model layer when the question is about relationship between view and controller. But yes the more accurate  answer is that calculations should be in the model.